# ActivityGroup with Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE throws RuntimeException

Tags: android, runtimeexception, activitygroup

I'm working with an `ActivityGroup` which is orientation-aware.

When the phone is in portrait-mode `Activity` A should be started.
When in landscape-mode `Activity` B should be started.

I do have a custom title in both of these activities, that is called within the corresponding `onCreate` methods.

I call the initialisation of the custom title like this:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);
    customTitleBar = new CustomTitleBar(getWindow());
    Log.d(TAG, "onCreate called");

    setContentView(R.layout.layout_a);
    customTitleBar.init();
    ...
}
```

And it all works when I'm launching each `Activity` on it's own.

But when trying to start them within the `ActivityGroup`, my app crashes with this exception:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {foo.bar.MyActivityGroup}:
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{foo.bar.ActivityA}:
android.util.AndroidRuntimeException:
You cannot combine custom titles with other title features
```

I'm not using any title feature within the `ActivityGroup`. Is anyone able to help me with this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems impossible to create an `ActivityGroup` with custom titled Activities in it. Creating a `Decorator` and passing the `Activity` into this decorator solves the issue.